# Give users permissions to edit documents but not customize Web Part Pages

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation

I want to create a permissions level that would give users access to view, add and edit items in a document library, but I don't want them to be able to modify the visual elements of the page. When I look at the List Permissions it seems I can't give users access to edit documents without also allowing them the ability to customize the page layout:
[image]

Am I understanding this correctly? If so how is there any way I can accomplish what I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They can't modify the pages of a regular library, only of pages that are stored in a document library. By default in 2010, there is a pages library on each team site that contains the "main" page of each site and can hold additional pages if created. If you want to prevent editing of that, just place unique permissions on that library.

Comment: Hmm I'm confused. I'm using the default "Documents" library in a subsite. When I go to Site Settings I see I can modify Site Permissions and Site App Permissions, but when I click on Site App permissions it tell me "There are no apps having explicit access to the site.". How can I set permissions on this library?

Comment: No offense, but if you are asking questions about custom permission levels without knowing about unique permissions for libraries then you have skipped some important training. 
Start here: http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/sharepoint-server-help/introduction-control-user-access-with-permissions-HA101794487.aspx